# How to revert toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, jquery, globalization

I need to convert a formatted number to JS default number format.

This is my code:

```
String.prototype.toJsFloatFormat = function() {
          debugger;
          var newVal = this;
          return newVal;
        }
//Example of use
var input = 10000.22; //default js format
var formatted = input.toLocaleString("es"); // result is: 10.000,22
var unformatted = formatted.toJsFloatFormat(); //expected result = 10000.22;
```

The problem is when I need to get the formatted number (10.000,22) and I make operations with this formatted number (parseFloat(10.000,22) + 1000) I have bad results ( parseFloat(10.000,22) + 1000 = 1010)

thanks in advance.

Comment: `toLocalString()` displays the number in your format but JavaScript isn't changing the format in which is calculates. You should do your calculations in the default format and use `toLocaleString` for display only.

Comment: Your API shouldn't have locale-formatted numeric strings, that's what needs to be fixed. Don't try to work around a buggy specification, fix the source of the problem.

Answer (score 11):

It's not easy. There's a reason why most of the comments have said "Don't try -
 do your calculations on the number itself, not the formatted value".

You need to work out what the decimal and thousand separator characters are. For that, you will need to know which locale the number was converted into.

```
(1234.5).toLocaleString("es").match(/(\D+)/g);
// -> [".", ","]
```

Once you have that, you can replace characters in the formatted string.

```
function unformatString(string, locale) {

    var parts = (1234.5).toLocaleString(locale).match(/(\D+)/g);
    var unformatted = string;

    unformatted = unformatted.split(parts[0]).join("");
    unformatted = unformatted.split(parts[1]).join(".");

    return parseFloat(unformatted);

}
```

There is no way of working out the locale - you have to know it and pass it to the function.

Answer (score 2):

no need to reinvent the wheel -
https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize#readme

```
var input = 10000.22; 
Globalize.parseFloat(input );
```

Comment: The input should be with quotes! The globalizedjs  is amazing!

Answer (score 2):

I did it this way(in my case it was the 'ru' local format, so I did replace the 'space' symbol):

```
var myNumber = 1000000;

var formated = myNumber.toLocaleString('ru');
var unformated = parseInt(formated.replace(/\s/g, ''));
```

your case:

```
var formated = myNumber.toLocaleString('en');
var unformated = parseInt(formated.replace(/,/g, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

I did this, that's fine for me

```
    function localeStringToFloat(locale){
    if(!locale) return locale

    let test=1000
    test=test.toLocaleString(undefined,{minimumFractionDigits: 2,maximumFractionDigits: 2});
    let separator=test[1]
    let decimalSeparator=test[5]

    return parseFloat(locale.replaceAll(separator,'').replace(decimalSeparator,'.'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the answer from James Long but in TypeScript, here it is :)

[Answer credits to James Long](https://stackoverflow.com/users/557019/james-long)

```
/**
 * This function will unformat a number that has been formatted using the passed locale
 * @param {string} number - The formatted number to unformat.
 * @param {string} locale - The locale used to format the number.
 * @returns {number} - Will return the unformatted number in case the conversion was successful,
 * otherwise it will return the original number using parseFloat to convert it to type number.
 */
export const unformatLocaleStringifyNumber = (
  number: string,
  locale: string,
): number => {
  const parts = (1234.5).toLocaleString(locale).match(/(\D+)/g);
  let unformatted = number;

  if (parts) {
    unformatted = unformatted.split(parts[0]).join('');
    unformatted = unformatted.split(parts[1]).join('.');
    return parseFloat(unformatted);
  }

  return parseFloat(number);
};
```

Answer (score -2):

My functions for format and unFormat currency numbers to 'en-US'. I hope helps

```
function myFormatPrice(num,digits){
    return num.toLocaleString('en-US', {maximumFractionDigits:digits});
}
function myUnFormatPrice(formated){
    return parseFloat( formated.replaceAll(',','') );
}
```