# Change timezone format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, moment-timezone

after chaning my date timezone using toLocalString()

```
new Date(dateParam).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: "Australia/Sydney" })
```

i've got this string `5/25/2022, 8:44:46 PM`, how can i transform from this format to default `new Date()` fromat `Tue Jul 05 2022 23:22:37 GMT+0300`, to be able to use Date methods(example: `toDateString(), getFullYear()`)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950796/how-to-revert-tolocalestring

Answer (score 0):

add to your solution two parameters dataStyle and timeStyle like in the example below

```
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', { dateStyle: 'full', timeStyle: 'long' }).format(date));
// Expected output "Sunday, 20 December 2020 at 14:23:16 GMT+11"
```

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me how to make the date object look like so that you can use its methods (exemple: toDateString(), getFullYear())?

Comment: `new Date(dateParam).toLocaleString('en-US', { dateStyle: 'full', timeStyle: 'long', timeZone: "Australia/Sydney" })`
try this solution